# Making a view of simple text sentences

Tags: views

My aim is to make a view of 20 sentences. The problem is all of them sit in the same Input-field and I really have no plans to open 20 different text-fields, i.e one for each sentence...

Is there Any way I could make a grid view of these 20 sentences easily from 1 input field? Thx.

Comment: I don't quite understand what do you mean by making a view from 20 sentences - do you want to display each sentence as a different row? If this is not what you mean, I suggest giving an example.

Comment: How about making the text field a multi-value field?

Comment: I've tried to use multi-value field but it didn't help... I.e, When I made the view greed, all was in the same column, and not in different columns.

Comment: I believe OP wants one field, split into 20 paragraphs essentially, but displayed in Views in a grid as though each paragraph was a separate field and thus displayed in it's own grid. I don't believe Views can do that on its own, since it designed to work with fields as a whole. You could create your own module to split one field into 20 fields visible to Views, but it's probably less work to just add 20 items of content...

Comment: That's exactly what I need @Geoff! Thank you! Do you have any recommendation for such a module? Ben.

Comment: sorry, I don't of any modules that would accomplish that - you would have to write something custom, but unless the content is changing often, it really would be much less work to create 20 pieces of content...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option:

- create a content type (sentence) with only a title (sentence 1, sentence 2, etc) and body
- create 20 pieces of sentence content, each with one of the sentences you want
- create a new View, content type: sentence, page, show 20, no pager, table of fields
- add the body field to the table, and remove the title

Now download the [Editable Views module](https://www.drupal.org/project/editableviews):

> Editable Views lets you create Views where the fields can be edited.
>   Fields show both the current value and a form to edit it. A 'Save'
>   button allows saving of all the entities shown in the View.
>
> Editable fields can be added on the base entity as well as on entities
>   brought into the View by a relationship. Other, non-editable fields
>   may be added to the View, in which case they function normally.

and set it up for that View of sentences.

- create your normal View of Grid, with the body field from the sentence content type and set it up however you would normally do so

With this set up, you can easily create the grid of sentences you want, plus it will create an easy way to edit those sentences (Editable Views) so that you don't need to go to 20 different pieces of content to update the field - it can all be be done from one View page